# Sharepoint 2013 Column validation not working

Tags: validation, if-statement, sharepoint, conditional-statements, sharepoint-2013

I have a few columns in a list and one is called Supervised, the other relevant one is called Co-Supervisor.

I'm trying to force Co-Supervisor not to be blank if Supervised="Yes" but cannot get the column validation to work!

I've tried several different formulas in the Co-Supervisor column validation settings. I always get an error. Please help!

This is an example of one of the formulas I've used:

```
=IF([Supervised]="Yes",TRUE,FALSE)
```

I've also tried:

```
=AND([Supervised]="Yes",(NOT(ISBLANK([Co-Supervisor])))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below formula:

1. GoTo List settings
2. GoTO validation settings
3. Use below mentioned formula

   **=IF([Supervised],IF([Co-Superviser]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)**

I have tested this on my environment and it is working fine.

(Note : Yes/No fields are internally stored as bit/boolean.So **IF[Supervised]** will directly evaluate to True/False.
Reference - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89188/calculated-column-issue-with-if-statement-and-yes-no-field
 )